# Arcmap not changing to landscape view?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layouts

Arcmap refuses to change my layout view to landscape when I change the options in Page and Print setup. It keeps the exact same portrait box as before.

Comment: Does your printer support landscape view? If so, the layout frame should change to landscape, but you'll still have to adjust the data frame.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to include screenshots of your Page and Print Setup and your Layout View, please?

Comment: I have found that when ArcMap is stubborn on its page layout settings it can be overcome by changing your printer to a data type (like XPS document writer) and setting the options there. There was a similar effect trying to create A0 PDF maps but the printer only supporting A4, that (I think) has been overcome now but it sounds like a similar situation. Give that a shot and see if it helps. If you don't like XPS then try Ghostscript PDF https://www.stat.tamu.edu/~henrik/GSPSprinter/GSPSprinter.html - my preference over XPS but max resolution is 300dpi.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issue. ArcGIS sometimes just bugs out due to code mysteries. One way the problem can be resolved is by opening a blank ArcMap document, switching the view in `page and print setup` to landscape, then adding your layers from the defective map to this new one.